# importing different timestamps to db2

Tags: import, timestamp, db2

I have a csv file including following timestamps

```
    2015-12-16T20:00:12.721Z,"2015-12-16T22:00:12.720+02:00"
```

I try to import or load this csv file to db2 but i get error about not valid timestamp SQL3192N. Is there any workaround to do this without editing csv file ?

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?  All (most?) versions don't support time zones/offsets on timestamps, which is what it's complaining about.  In the first value it's the `Z` (thankfully that means the value's in UTC), and possibly the date/time separator.  In the second one it's most likely the offset - although I'm a little surprised you're getting two different styles of timestamps.

Comment: You best bet may be to use PureXML functions to parse the timestamps which appear to adhere to `xs:dateTime` specs.